# Change nativescript android api version

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I am using:

```
nativescript has an 8.0.1 version and is up to date.
@nativescript/core has an 8.0.4 version and is up to date.
@nativescript/ios are not installed.
@nativescript/android has an 8.0.0 version and is up to date.
```

I am trying to get my app to target `minSdkVersion` 19, but no matter what I do, the app is compiled with version 17.

I tried:

- Setting `minSdkVersion 19` in `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`
- Adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>` to `App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

I've looked around and I can't find the solution, though I have come across a few posts about the same issue. None of them solved the issue.

The project in question is [here](https://github.com/FREEVSE/app.git), just clone it and run `tns build android`. It will build with `android-platform-17.d.ts`. If you want to see the build fail when using a type from platform 19, just add `let test = new android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback()`.

Comment: Setting the value in `App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` worked for me. maybe you needed to `ns clean` then build it again ? ( or even `tns platform remove android ` then `add` ? ) ...

Answer (score 1):

The default value in the file `node_modules/@nativescript/types-android/lib/android.d.ts` is `<reference path="./android-17.d.ts" />` so it is building with `android-platform-17.d.ts`. Try changing the value to `<reference path="./android-19.d.ts" />` in that file and build it.

I tried to build after changing it in your code and due to a different reason the build failed which is `Cannot create an instance of an abstract class`. This error occurred because `android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback` is actually a class but you are trying to use it like a function.

Comment: This is actually how I've worked around the issue for now, but obviously it's not a great solution as the wrong value returns anytime I clean and rebuild the project. Any idea how I can change this? It doesn't make sense that the package has the types for all versions of the sdk but you can't use them...